# How to cut numeric vector into intervals with maximum length of i-th interval equall n

Tags: r

For example I have a vector: `a = my_function(1000)`!

```
head(a,15)
 [1]  0.4011032  0.4867019  0.9831197  1.1138037  3.2740297  3.7853916  4.6833426  6.9224802  7.5878639
[10]  8.0706788  8.4404792  9.4149317  9.4176043 10.2345215 11.1884374
```

I want to use `cut` function(or some alternative) to divide this vector into intervals. BUT I want, that maximum size of each interval will be, for example, 5.

**EDITED:**

breaks: `breaks <- seq(from = 1, by = 4,length.out = 100)`

So the first interval is: `(1,5]` . And first seven variables of `a` vector falls into this interval. But I want, that size of each intervall to be 5. It means that first 5 variables

```
[1]  0.4011032  0.4867019  0.9831197  1.1138037  3.2740297
```

lies in first interval. And variables `3.7853916  4.6833426` lies in second interval(with length equall 5).
How can I do that?

Comment: Define size. Length, range?

Comment: @ddunn801 Edited. Take a look please once again

Comment: @jogo But I think your code works only for n = 100.

Comment: I think your question is still imprecise... Your `a` vector is your set of breaks, not an interval. First 10 are 1,6,13,19,25,31,37,43,49,55. How do those 10 fall in your interval `(1,7]`? If you want a "number of elements that fall inside your interval" to be 5, then you should use a modulus and a `sort()` or `order()` subsequently to the `cut()` or `quantile()` function. If you want "the interval to be of size 5", then your question is definitely not very clear... since 7-2 = 5 and 13-7 = 6, you're using some example numbers that really muddy up your intentions.

Comment: @quickreaction I edited my question once more. Hope that everything is clear right now:)

Comment: @jogo do you have an idea how to do that?

Comment: What structure your resulting object should have?

Comment: @jogo ideally vector. Or data.frame

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
a <- rnorm(100)
a <- sort(a)
b <- matrix(data = a, nrow = 10, ncol = 10, dimnames = list(1:10))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new variable which defines the group of belongness, just sorting the values and labeling them with a number (each one repeated 5 times).

```
cbind(sort(rnorm(100)), rep(1:20,each=5))
```

Note thate in `rep`, instead of 1:20 you should put `n/5` being `n` the number of elements.

If you need to define the intervals, you need only to define theme using the median between the highest value of one set and the minimum one of the following.

Comment: It is almost what I want to get. But how to deal with cases, when  some inteval is missed(For example no elements fall into some interval)

Comment: As defined before, there is not goint to be that case, but it could be your intervals are for different wide.

Comment: @DanielYefimov, in your question, you're changing the definition of your intervals. You can't get both, "intervals of five elements" and "elements that fall into intervals `[0,5); [5,10)`" because they are two different questions. @jsb's answer works for intervals of 10 elements, @R18's answer works for intervals of 5 elements. In order to do fixed boundaries, you can use `Hmisc::cut2(a,cuts=c(0:5*5))`. If you want to chop those into smaller vectors, you can `lapply` and backfill `NA`'s if `length(myInterval)!=5`. But your description still doesn't adequately describe the problem